# Where are the encoding_types stored in the system tables?

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I query `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` I see a column of `encoding_type`s. These are IDs, not strings.

When I query `pg_catalog.pg_table_def` I see a column of `encoding`s which *are* strings.

So far, I've reversed-engineered the following subset of the table I'm looking for:

```
id    description
128   none
131   lzo
```

Where are these encodings stored so I can complete my table?

Answer (score 0):

This [issue on AWS Labs Github](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/issues/308) mentions a (possibly undocumented?) function called `format_encoding` which converts the integer representation called `attencodingtype` into a string:

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
attencodingtype, format_encoding(attencodingtype) attencoding
FROM
pg_catalog.pg_attribute;
```

This will show you all the currently used encodings in your database, their `attencodingtype` and the associated string representation.